# Serialize object using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

How can I serialize and deserialize this object with gson to json:

```
public class test{

@Expose
public List< Pair<Double,Double> > list;

@Expose
public int alpha;
}
```

I've tried this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
String str = gson.toJson(testInstance,test.class);
```

where testInstance is an instance of class test, but it's not working because of Pair structure in List.

Comment: Could you change Pair class? If yes, you have to add @Expose annotation to each property which you want serialize to JSON. If no, you can create similar class in your program and add annotations.

Comment: Thank you for answer that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured `Gson` object using `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation` method.
From [documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation%28%29):

> Configures Gson to exclude all fields from consideration for
>   serialization or deserialization that do not have the Expose
>   annotation.

Could you change Pair class? If yes, you have to add `@Expose` annotation to each property which you want serialize to JSON. If no, you can create similar class in your program and add annotations.

Answer (score 0):

if the object is of a generic type, then the Generic type information is lost because of `Java Type Erasure`. You can solve this problem by specifying the correct parameterized type for your generic type. 
Try parameterized type like `List<String>`. This should work